# swfupload no longer works IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, swfupload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [swfupload not working under IE anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204871/swfupload-not-working-under-ie-anymore)

I have buit a website which uses swfupload to upload multiple images to our site.

Just recently realised that SWFUPLOAD doesnt work with IE9, none of the upload buttons display.  This is a major issue as many people use IE9.

Has anyone got any solutions to fix the problem with SWFUPLOAD.  Is swfupload supported anymore, or are they any other good alternative solutions I could use?